# Do isolation levels only apply to SELECTS and not UPDATES?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

Do isolation levels only apply to SELECTS and not UPDATES?

Scenario that demonstrated different isolation behavior for SELECTS

```
1) 0:00 Thread A runs a query that returns 1000 rows that takes 5 minutes to complete
2) 0:02 Thread B runs a query that returns the same 1000 rows
3) 0:05 Thread A updates the last 1 rows in this result set and commits them
4) 0:07 Thread B's query returns*
```

Depending on the isolation level, the result set in #4 will either contain Thread A's changes or it won't. **Is the same true for UPDATES?**

The following is an example scenario:

```
Thread A: UPDATE ... WHERE primary_key = 1234 AND version = 5
Thread B: UPDATE ... WHERE primary_key = 1234 AND version = 5
```

If both Thread A and Thread B enter their transactions at the same time, and Thread B performs its update after Thread A, will Thread B's update fail or will it "see" the record with version 5 and therefore succeed?

Does it depend on the database? e.g. Oracle vs MySql vs PostgreSQL?

Comment: Note, this is similar to, but different from my more specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426096/how-to-correctly-implement-optimistic-locking-in-mysql. Figured it would be beneficial to ask this more general question about isolation levels, for myself and for folks wondering about this more general question.

Comment: A query will not see changes made after it started, it works on a snapshot taken when it starts. So I think the premise of the question is wrong: the resultset in #4 will never have thread A changes whatever the isolation level.

Comment: @Daniel- this is wrong. There are certainly isolation levels that would allow thread b to see thread a's changes while both are in concurrent transactions

Comment: @BestPractices - Daniel is correct, at least for Oracle.  From the [Database Concepts book](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#BABEAGIA): "Oracle Database never permits dirty reads, which occur when a transaction reads uncommitted data in another transaction."

Comment: Oracle supports READ COMMITTED which is committed data from another transaction. So yes, one thread that enters a transaction at the same time as another thread, in Oracle, when one thread writes data in its own transaction, can be read by the other thread during its seperate transaction. Please note the original question -- which is "Do isolation levels only apply to SELECTS and not UPDATES?". If anyone can answer this question, please post it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you meant to show an "optimistic locking" pattern as used by many ORMs, like:

```
Thread A: UPDATE ... SET ..., version = 6 WHERE primary_key = 1234 AND version = 5
Thread B: UPDATE ... SET ..., version = 6 primary_key = 1234 AND version = 5
```

then in all sensible isolation levels (I'm not 100% sure about READ UNCOMMITTED - most DBs don't even support it) thread B will match no rows and have no effect.

In PostgreSQL for example, thread B will initially match the same row as A, but block on a row update lock until thread A commits or rolls back. At this point it'll re-check the condition and find that it no longer matches if thread A committed, so it'll do nothing. The row locking will mean that serialization conflicts never come into play in this particular case.

In any sane database only one of the two updates will succeed - the second will either match zero rows or abort with a serialization failure, depending on the isolation level and DB implementation. This is true even in MySQL with InnoDB ([see detailed explanation and demo in this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28890/7788)) at least in 5.5. If you're using MyISAM then correctness and reliability are clearly not big concerns for you ;-)

I'm not aware of any database that applies different isolation rules to `UPDATE`s vs `SELECT`s. After all, an `UPDATE` needs the same isolation guarantees for its `WHERE` clause, subqueries, etc, as a `SELECT`. `UPDATE`s can deadlock which `SELECT`s can't (in PostgreSQL; apparently they can in MySQL+InnoDB). Unlike `SELECT`, `UPDATE`s are subject to serialization failures in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation mode - but they have the same visibility rules.

PostgreSQL's documentation on [concurrency control](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html) explains this pretty well.

Comment: The PostgreSQL documentation was useful. It is clear to me now that PostgreSQL and MySQL with InnoDB have different transaction behavior, even though they look like they would be/should be similar on the face of it (but comparing the concurrency/transaction documentation between the two shows the two behave differently in certain circumstances). Note, SELECTS can deadlock in MySQL with InnoDB, if you want to update your answer.

Comment: @BestPractices Updated. Presumably that's because in InnoDB, writers can block readers?

Comment: @BestPractices and you're quite right, especially in `SERIALIZABLE` transactions they will differ. Even PostgreSQL 9.1+ is quite different to PostgreSQL 9.0 and older re `SERIALIZABLE` isolation.

Comment: @BestPractices Added a link showing that update concurrency works as described in MySQL+InnoDB, same as PostgreSQL for this simple case at least.

Comment: @Craig: this part is misleading: _in all sensible isolation levels...thread B will match no rows and have no effect_. With oracle and PG in serializable level, B would fail with a serialization error. As for mysql, its behavior is so different that it's hard to define by comparing it to the others.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, there is a [statement-level consistency](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#i5700):

> Oracle Database always enforces statement-level read consistency, which guarantees that data returned by a single query is committed and consistent with respect to a single point in time.

This means that your SELECT example would not work like this in Oracle: the thread B will return the results from the select, as they were at the beginning of the statement. This means that Oracle may re-create past blocks from undo data as they were when the query began, so that the result of the long running query makes sense. The changes made by the update in point (3) would not be present in the result.

**A select query will not see the transaction changes made after it has begun, even if they are committed.**

Updates work similarly but involves some extra work. All updates/deletes start with a standard SELECT with standard point-in-time consistency, but the blocks are asked in `CURRENT MODE`. This is because the block version that has to be modified is the last one. Furthermore, the last one is also the one that contains information about current locks on the block. Tom Kyte has a [nice analogy](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:878847787577) for DML (works the same for delete and update):

> Think of the delete being processed like this:
>
> ```
> for x in ( select rowid from emp )   --- CONSISTENT GETS
> loop
>    delete from emp where rowid = x.rowid;  --- CURRENT MODE GETS
> end loop;
> ```

Now what would happen in your scenario if we replace our SELECT by an update?

First, if the row is still locked (transaction in point (3) hasn't been committed), the update in point (4) will wait -- until either (3) commits or rollbacks.

If  the transaction has committed and if you're in `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation, of course you will get an error. We don't want to modify data that has been altered since the beginning of the transaction (because those changes are invisible).

In `READ COMMITED`, there is an interesting, not intuitive development. When Oracle gets the row that was modified, it realizes that the data has been modified after the start of the query. Oracle can't process the update now, since this wouldn't be consistent (furthermore, that would imply a case of *lost update*). So Oracle **restarts** its query, as described in this [other askTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:11504247549852):

> The result set is consistent -- but it may well be consistent as of a restart time.

We get a second "select" which will this time (hopefully) get all rows in a consistent fashion. Since locks are placed row by row, all rows found in the first pass should still be available (they couldn't have been modified by another transaction between the first pass and the second).